# iOS; NSAutoreleasePool is obsolete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

I am following a youtube video about CSV data access. But I have seen in the framework that `NSAutoreleasePool` is specified as obsolete. Have we got another way to develop access to CSV data file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@autoreleasepool {
   // parse your CSV
}
```

Comment: it doesn't have to be iOS 5 and above

Answer (score 4):

The "brackets" `pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]` and `[pool drain];` have been replaced with `@autoreleasepool { <stuff between the "brackets> }`.

Answer (score 1):

`@autoreleasepool` is not at all obsolete in iOS5++. In some cases you MUST set up your own autorelease pool, see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).
The most important cases are 1) if you have code that creates many temporary objects that could be released before the app returns to the main run loop (you should), and 2) if you setup a separate thread (you must).

Comment: He asked for NSAutoreleasePool ;)

Comment: @HAS: And why did you downvote my answer??? I think it is completely right, and it answers to the question.

Comment: @HAS: Sorry, when I looked at this page, my answer had a downvote of -1, and you were the only one who left a comment, a negative one. BTW I believe my answer is indeed a valid answer to the question, and obviously somebody else had also this opinion.

Comment: (I also did not downvote) I also don't think you answered the question, because nowhere does it ask about `@autoreleasepool`. It only asks about `NSAutoreleasePool`, which indeed should be switched over to `@autoreleasepool`, which is probably what the OP is asking about. (Not that the question makes much sense though anyway.)

Comment: @HAS & newacct: So, I did understand the question wrongly. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: Did you intend to say "NSAutoreleasePool is not at all obsolete" instead of "@autoreleasepool is not at all obsolete"?